# bibLaTeX authoryear citation style with unknown year

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I have an `@inbook` reference in my bibtex library with an unknown year. Since I use the bibLaTeX authoryear citation style with some customizations my normal citations (with known year) look like:

> Author1/Author2/Author3 (year)

But when there is no year defined it will display the title of the reference where it should be:

> Author1/Author2/Author3

What do I have to redefine in order to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the `xpatch` package and then "patch" the `cite` bib macro as follows:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}{\usebibmacro{cite:label}}{\printnames{labelname}}{}{}
```

CAVEAT: It might be possible to have bibliography entries where there is no author nor year. In such cases, what you propose result in an empty reference (nothing is going to be printed).  A more substantial change is need to handle such cases, namely:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\ifnameundef{labelname}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
          {\printnames{labelname}}%
          \setunit{\addspace}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```